# How to make spiral with editable vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

I want to make a (very rough) model of a cochlea in an ear. However, whenever I look up a spiral tutorial (I'm very new to Blender) and follow it, it has me make a spiral that when looked at in edit mode only has vertices in the center of the spiral. If I want to make some parts of the spiral wider, for example, I cannot do that. I need vertices on the outside. Does anyone know how to do this? I don't really know if I'm explaining this right.

Comment: I need coffee. I read "How to make spiral with edible vertices." which made me do a double-take.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the radius of parts of a curve by selecting the control points and changing the *Mean Radius* value in the <kbd>N</kbd> *> Item > Transform* panel. Once  you're reasonably happy with the curve, if you want to have the vertices on the surface, you can convert it to *mesh* by selecting *Convert to > Mesh* from the right click menu. It'll probably harder to control as a mesh though, since you'll lose the parametric nature of the curve, so I'd suggest making a copy first.

[image]

As a bonus, if you enable the "*Add Curve: Extra Objects*" add-on from *Preferences > Add-ons*, you get many curve presets in your *Add* menu (<kbd>Shift+A</kbd>), like so:

[image]

Comment: I actually used the add-on in the tutorial, I just wanted the "convert to mesh." Thanks! And I'll use the radius tip too.

Answer (score 3):

They probably used modifiers to create the spiral.  You can apply all of the modifiers at once by entering *Object Mode* and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> -> *Visual Geometry to Mesh*.

Here's an example default cube with *Bevel* and *Subdivision Surface* modifiers.

[image]