# Bevel Modifier Not Working Correctly

Tags: modeling

Long story short, I created a cube and applied the bevel modifier. In the object view, everything looks fine. When I go into edit mode, however, what I see in the viewport looks like the wireframe of the original cube, with the beveled version inside it. When I try to select a face, Blender will only let me select faces on the original unbeveled cube (see the attached image). I just want the beveled version so I can work on it. How do I get rid of the original? [image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/254724/110840

Comment: Modifiers take the base mesh and apply a procedure to display a result in real-time, but the base object is actually just what you see in edit mode.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't look like you've applied the modifier, so for the moment the bevel is only virtual, click on *Apply* or select the modifier and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>:

[image]